# Trying to scan the number of newlines in a user designated file in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to count the number of newlines in a file named testprog. Though the user needs to input the file name so it is versatile. The program compile but I keep having a segmentation fault.

testprog is as follows

```
Rd 5000  
st n 2017  
ld zero 1014  
st sum 2016  
L: ld n 1017  
Add sum 3016  
St sum 2016  
Ld n 1017  
Sub one 4015  
St n 2017  
Brgt L 8004  
Ld sum 1016  
Wr 6000  
Stop 0000  
Zero: 0 0000  
One: 1 0001  
Sum: 0 0000  
N: 0 0000
```

The code i have is

```
int main()
{
 unsigned int Line = 0;
 int ch;
 FILE *My_file;
 char command;                              
 //the command being entered

 do
 {
  printf("Command: ");
  scanf("%s",&command);
  if (command=='l'||command=='L')           
  //loads file name to 'memory'
  {
   printf("load file name: "); 
   scanf(" %s",memory);
   My_file = fopen(memory,"r"); 
   while (EOF != (ch=getc(My_file)))
   {
    if ( ch == '\n' )
     Line++;
   }
```

The command entered is L; the file name is testprog, I receive a segmentation fault after i press enter for the file name. Im looking to receive 17 as the value for line, though i wish for the program to be versatile so that later with testprog2 it sends the right number of lines to Line. I have been searching online for hours for help to no avail. Thank you very much for any help you can give.

Comment: The program is full of errors and does not even compile. Please provide a [mcve]. From the code given, I'd recommend you recap about pointers and how `scanf` works in a good C book. No offence!

Comment: `char command;` --> `char command[128];` (128 : Size to be with your need)

Comment: You also want to avoid `scanf ("%s", ....)` it poses significant security concerns similar to `gets()`. There is nothing wrong with `scanf`, but the use of the format specifier `%s` alone allows a virtually unlimited number of character to be provided as input.

Comment: None taken olaf im sorry i should have put the whole program up, then recaped the problem area thank you for the critque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a segfault because you are trying to scan a non-empty string into a single-character variable:

```
scanf("%s", &command); // command is char
```

Since C strings are null-terminated, the value you enter gets written into `command`, and `'\0'` terminator gets written into the location one past the end of `command`, causing undefined behavior.

To fix this problem make `command` an array, and provide a limit to `scanf`, like this:

```
char command[2];
scanf("%1s", command); // %1s tells scanf that the string is at most one-char long
```

Now you need to use `command[0] ==` in place of `command == ...` to interpret the command.

Comment: I am still having issues, i will let you know when i get it working and how.